# R roll using dates not allowed?

Tags: r, join, data.table

For creating a table I need to match people's visits to one place (say, church) to visits to another (say, the shop). In this simplified example I need to find the first time people went to church, and the last time before each church visit they went to the shop. So given

```
> test_church=data.table(subject=as.factor(c('S_01','S_01','S_02','S_02')),
    date=as.Date(c('2018-01-15','2018-01-29','2018-01-08','2018-01-22')),
    key='subject')

> test_shop=data.table(subject=as.factor(c('S_01','S_02','S_01','S_02',
                                         'S_01','S_02','S_01','S_02')),
                     date=as.Date(c('2018-01-03','2018-01-7',
                                    '2018-01-11','2018-01-14',
                                    '2018-01-17','2018-01-20',
                                    '2018-01-23','2018-01-26')),
                     key='subject')

> str(test_church)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ subject: Factor w/ 2 levels "S_01","S_02": 1 1 2 2
 $ date   : Date, format: "2018-01-15" "2018-01-29" ...
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "subject"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> str(test_shop)
 Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 8 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ subject: Factor w/ 2 levels "S_01","S_02": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
 $ date   : Date, format: "2018-01-03" "2018-01-11" ...
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr  "subject" "date"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

the church visits I'm looking for are `"2018-01-15"` for `S_01` and `"2018-01-08"` for `S_02` and the corresponding last shop visits before those are `"2018-01-11"` for `S_01` (last before `"2018-01-15"`) and `"2018-01-07"` for `S_02` (last before `"2018-01-08"`).

My actual tables are much bigger (that is why I want to use data.table functions) but the relevant columns are `subject` and `date`.

The first church visit per subject I find with

```
first_church = test_church[ J(unique(subject)), on = 'subject', mult = 'first' ]
```

but then when I want to find the corresponding shop visit with

```
church_shop = test_shop[ first_church, on='date', roll=T ]
```

I get

```
> church_shop
   subject       date i.subject
1:    S_02 2018-01-15      S_01
2:    S_02 2018-01-08      S_02
```

So instead of finding dates for the right visits, I get a list of subjects in my new table that is not even correct! (`S_02` does not do anything on `"2018-01-15"`). The same thing happens if I set the keys of both `first_church` and `test_shop` to `c('subject','date')`.

Is there a way to do this with joins or should I just write a for loop?

Comment: You mean `on=c("subject", "date")`?

Comment: I think I have had this problem before.  Try casting all the dates to numeric -- the join should work then -- and then you can cast them back to Date

Comment: @Frank I did that, but then got an error that the join columns were not integer, double or character...

Comment: ...I think that is the same problem that @C8H10N4O2 mentioned (and solved). The result of the join is the same though.

Comment: Maybe when you tried it you put date before subject -- only the final column in the on= expression is "rolled" on, and that's why it needs to be orderable

Comment: No I use `c('subject','date')`. I think the problem with the bigger data set is that for some subjects, date alone is not always a unique identifier. When it is unique there is no problem, when it isn't, I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding what should be a faster way to get first church visit and incorporating Frank's comment to get your desired output:

```
#get first church visit
setorder(test_church, subject, date)
first_church <- test_church[test_church[, .I[1L], by=.(subject)]$V1]

#rolling join with Frank's fix
test_shop[first_church, .(x.subject, x.date), on=c("subject", "date"), roll=TRUE]
```

output:

```
   x.subject     x.date
1:      S_01 2018-01-11
2:      S_02 2018-01-07
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I tried the join on both columns but then got an error that join columns need to be integer or character (and subject is neither). Will now try it on the bigger data set. I'm not sure I understand the `first_church` line. Would that do the same as `setorder(church,'subject')`?

Comment: Can you share the ‘str’ of these 2 columns?

Comment: Sure, I have put them in the post.

Comment: Can you convert your subject columns into character class first? You can use as.character